# Should linux cron jobs be specified with an "&" to indicate to run in background?

Tags: linux, cron

In a crontab file, should commands be specified with a trailing "&", or will the command run in the background anyway?

I have:

```
*/20 * * * * /home/me/monitor/check.sh /home/me/monitor/check.properties  >> /home/me/monitor/check.log 2>&1 &
```

I've seen contradictory answers to this question in various places. Some say no need to put an "&", others that without the ampersand cron waits for output from the command, even though all output is redirected.

Comment: seems like this is only for @reboot commands

Answer (score 123, accepted):

Every job that's run by systemd-cron (and most other implementations?) is run in the background automatically, so no need for the `&`.

Comment: Thank you. What cron todo if I specify "&" at end of commend ?

Comment: Busybox cron (maybe others) will not start the same job while a previous one is already running.

Comment: @ColinM just yday asked relevant question about busybox' cron: https://superuser.com/q/1803513/179401  Any idea 1) where is this documented 2) whether adding `&` in busybox crontab should thus be used?